Express.js individual route middleware is affecting other routes defined later
Custom middleware functions on some of my individual routes seems to be running on routes defined later in the same file. The middleware is not running on those routes defined later, however. Here's an example:
const router = require('express').Router()

const Controller = require('../controller')
const AuthMiddleware = require('../middleware/authentication')

router.post('/upload_file', AuthMiddleware.checkPermissions, Controller.uploadFile)

// AuthMiddleware.checkPermissions is getting called for these two
router.get('/image', Controller.getImage)
router.get('/video', Controller.getVideo)

The middleware on the /upload_file route is getting called for the /image and /video routes since they return an HTTP 401 Unauthorized.
I defined the two GET routes before the POST route and it fixed the issue:
...

// Now they return an HTTP 200
router.get('/image', Controller.getImage)
router.get('/video', Controller.getVideo)

router.post('/upload_file', AuthMiddleware.checkPermissions, Controller.uploadFile)

Only some of my routes seem to be experiencing this problem, and I can't figure out why. I would think the middleware function is supposed to run only on the route it's used with.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

You're right about how it should behave. So most likely reason is that you've made a mistake somewhere. Go find it, good luck.

What type of mistake should I be looking for that would cause this type of behavior to occur? Is it with router-level middleware, etc.? I am working on an existing app that I inherited.

Not sure what kind of answer you're hoping for. With the risk of sounding condescending... you're looking for the type of mistake that adds/calls your middleware from an unexpected place. Maybe it's added with router.use(...) somewhere further up/down the chain.

@super Thank you! Not condescending at all. I will look for the issue.
